# m2eclipse imported project naming

Tags: eclipse, plugins, maven

When importing a Maven project into Eclipse, the project name is currently generated from the artifactId. Can I change this in a way that the name from the "name"-Tag inside the POM is used instead?

Answer (score 1):

The (Eclipse) project name is encoded in the .project file residing in your project directory.

You may change this using a text editor to any value you want.

By checking in the .project file you can persist this information.

Comment: I should have stated in my question that I want this to be done automatically when Eclipse imports the project. I don't think it is a good idea to check in .project with a Maven project (or any other files that are generated automatically).

Comment: Hmm - even specifying [name] in the advanced naming options doesn't fool the m2eclipse plugin so I think you are out of luck here until the plugin implementation would support that.